# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Jsf 2 Font error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2, fonts

I am trying to integrate Twitter Bootstrap 3 carousel with a jsf application. At one point I need to include the glyphicons fonts into the application so that the right and left navigation should work.

After looking into some posts in the stackoverflow, I understood that the url pointing in the bootstrap.css is incorrect and need to be modified to use resources of JSF 2.

The carousel is displaying fine but the navigation is not working fine and below error is displaying in console

**WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular.  To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
Jul 23, 2014 7:08:03 PM com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular, from library, fonts.**

The following is the change I made in bootstrap.css

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';


src: url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}");
src: url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}?#iefix")    format('embedded-opentype'), 
   url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff']}") format('woff'), 
   url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf']}") format('truetype'), 
   url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular']}") format('svg');
}
```

All the required files are present in Webcontent/resources/fonts/ folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are using a Faces Servlet sufix (like: *.xhtml, whatever) and then JSF is appending this sufix to svg font file

So this code you wrote:

`url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular']}") format('svg');`

It would result this:

`url("/your_web_app/javax.faces.resource/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular.xhtml?ln=fonts")`

But this file "glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular.xhtml" does not exist.

Change your code to this:

`url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg']}#glyphicons_halflingsregular") format('svg');`

It will result this:

`url("/your_web_app/javax.faces.resource/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg.xhtml?ln=fonts#glyphicons_halflingsregular")`

And your problem is going to be solved!

Forgive my poor English :)